# Opencv2 crashes when the default constructor for ogl::Arrays runs

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to run one of the code examples that opencv2 provides ('opengl_interop.cpp'). In the code there's the following struct of several objects that throws an error. I've reduced the code down to the following simple program:

```
#include <opencv2/core/opengl.hpp>

struct DrawData {
    cv::ogl::Arrays arr;
    cv::ogl::Buffer indices;
    cv::ogl::Texture2D tex;
};


int main() {
    DrawData data;
    return 0;
}
```

The debugger identifies the 'Arrays' default constructor from  as the culprit, and the exception is thrown in the body of the constructor during runtime:

```
inline
cv::ogl::Arrays::Arrays() : size_(0)
{
}
```

The compiler (Visual Studio 2015) provides the following message:
"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAFA927788 in basic opengl program.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000B51399F360."

In the debugger console I get the following error message: "OpenCV(3.4.3) Error: No OpenGL support (The library is compiled without OpenGL support) in `anonymous-namespace'::throw_no_ogl, file c:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\opengl.cpp, line 60"

I'm on Windows 10 with an otherwise working copy of opencv2 3.4.3 installed. Thanks.

EDIT: opencv was built with opengl enabled. 'CMakeCache.txt' in my build folder shows the following line: `//Include OpenGL support 
WITH_OPENGL:BOOL=ON`

Comment: To be clear, does this happen during compilation or when running the program.

Comment: it happens at runtime

Comment: Prebuilt opencv does not support opengl. You have to build opencv with the flag `ENABLE_OPENGL=ON`.

Comment: opencv was built with opengl enabled. 'CMakeCache.txt' in my build folder shows the following:   
"//Include OpenGL support  
WITH_OPENGL:BOOL=ON"

Comment: it seems the error is on line 454 of https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/opengl.cpp That is for the Buffer constructor. It could be from Arrays, but I can't find its constructor. Can you check if HAVE_OPENGL is defined?

Comment: this seems to be it. HAVE_OPENGL is not defined, and defining it at any point in the code doesn't seem to take. Which is odd, because I've definitely built the binaries with it, and opengl32.dll was located during the make process.

Comment: You can write any assumptions here but opencv tells to you definitely that it is built without opengl support. Try to call `cv::getBuildInformation()` if you doesn't trust the error message.

Comment: You're correct this does seem to be the issue. Not sure why or how it keeps building without support, i've tried everything to get it to work

Comment: You might mix binaries of different configs.

Comment: really bummed that that's the only answer at this point. opencv is 18 years old.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by getting an older version of opencv (4.3.4), installing both Qt4 and Qt5, using the gui Cmake to verify that the install was correct and that opengl was included, and carefully linking everything and testing afterward.